# I am receiving this error, while I run the robot script, how can I resolve my server

Tags: android-studio, automation, appium, robotframework

*** Settings ***
Library    AppiumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Open_Application
Open Application      http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub    platformName=Android    platformVersion=11      deviceName=emulator-5554    appPackage=chat21.android.demo     appActivity=chat21.android.demo.SplashActivity - Chat21       automationName=Uiautomator2

{"status":9,"value":{"error":"unknown command","message":"The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource","stacktrace":""}}

Answer (score 0):

Please add installation details as well as the code that you are running. It seems that you have problem with configuration of the libraries.